# Override toString() but the data type is Integer

Tags: java

When I run this code the output is (MyInt@15db9742)-Object Address-:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyInt myInt = new MyInt(2);
    System.out.println(myInt);
}

class MyInt {
   public int val;
   public MyInt(int val){
       this.val = val;
   }
}
```

What I want to do is: to print the val without myInt.val

I tried to override toString()?!

```
public String toString(){
  return ""+val;
}
```

and it works! But I want the return type to be int/Integer NOT String,  and there is a compiler error

> The return type is incompatible with Object.toString()"

when I change the return type to int. Is there a way to do that?

EDIT:

In Short:

```
Integer integer =  new Integer(5);
int INT = integer;
System.out.println(INT);
```

So I want myClass "MyInt" works Like class "Integer"
so I can assign int val directly

```
MyInt myInt = new MyInt(5);
int INT = myInt; // I don't need to type "myInt.val"
System.out.println(INT);
```

Comment: Why would you want to change the return type? If you want a method that returns an `int` just make a different method.

Comment: No.  The whole point of `toString()` is to convert a class **to a String**.

Comment: I want the (int val) to be returned whenever I  call the object myInt. For Example: String s = new String("Hello"); print(s); it will return "Hello" not the address

Comment: You cannot override a method and changing is return type. You can have a method `toString()` with an Integer as return type, but in this case we talk as overloading not overriding.

Comment: What do you mean by "whenever I call the object myInt"? You don't call an object, you call a method.

Comment: Regarding the edit: What you want to do is (auto) unboxing and (AFAIK) it is not possible in Java (for custom classes - it's a language feature that only works with the [provided wrapper classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)).

Comment: Thanks a lot !! This is what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what happens behind the scenes when you call this:

```
System.out.println(myInt);
```

The `println` method takes an `Object` argument and then calls the `.toString()` method on that object. The `toString()` method always returns a string. Therefore what you did (return a string) was correct.

Note that when you do this:

```
System.out.println(1);
```

then there is an overload of `println` specifically for `int` arguments. But you can't pass an Object to `println` and expect it to be treated as a primitive type.

Comment: So when I create an object of "Integer i = new Integer(3); System.out.println(i);" it actually returns i.toString()?

Comment: Indeed. See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong on a **conceptual** and code quality level.

The method is called **toString()**.

Every Java programmer knows what this thing is supposed to do (to provide a **string** representation of the object you call it on).

Every Java programmer expects this method to return a **String**, and not an int.

Long story short: instead of overriding existing methods and totally changing their behavior (what is a super-bad idea by the way): simply add your own, new method and give that a reasonable name.

Finally: what you have in mind (changing the "contract" of methods) is most often a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Meaning: don't do things because you *could* do them. Instead really learn and understand the concepts that you intend to use. What I am saying: **proper inheritance** in good OO designs is **much** more than putting some **extends** keyword somewhere; and some @Override in front of a method declaration.

Comment: No Comment !   <><><>

Comment: I have to admit: I am not sure what you intend to tell me with your non-comment.